# Como usar $interval y $watch en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tengo una función que hace una petición al servidor y me trae datos en `JSON` y guardo en la variable `numero` un número cualquiera:

```
var numero

$scope.Cola = function() {

    Ticket.Colaservices({

        id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
        token: LoginData.getData().token,
        id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
        id_moduloatencion: LoginData.getData().moduloatencion_id

    }, function (response) {

        $scope.DateCola = response.data;
        var rut = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data.rut.split('.').join('')));
        numero = response.data.numero;
        $scope.rutsinpunto = rut;

    });

};

$scope.Cola();
```

Esto se produce al entrar a la página. Más adelante tengo un botón `llamar` que se comunica con el servidor y un `token` y como respuesta retorna un nuevo número, para obtenerlo tengo que actualizar la función de arriba, el problema es que el retorno es asíncronico, es decir que en cualquier momento me puede llegar.

Para obtenerlo hago lo siguiente:

```
$scope.llamar = function() {

    //mando ciertos datos
    Llamado.Llamar({
        id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
        token: LoginData.getData().token,
        id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
        id_moduloatencion: LoginData.getData().moduloatencion_id
    }, function (response) {

        // y en la respuesta creo un interval y ejecuto $scope.Cola() y muestro en consola la variable numero para saber cuando cambie, ¡cosa que sí hace!

        var resultado = $interval(function () {
            $scope.Cola();
            console.log(numero);
        }, 1000);

        // acá creo un watch para detectar el cambio ¡pero no funciona! no reconoce cuando es distinto el numero.

        $scope.$watch(numero, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue === oldValue) {
                return;
            }
            $interval.cancel(resultado);
            alert("el nuevo valor es " + newValue + " y el antiguo es: " + oldValue);

        });

    });

};
```

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? la idea es que cuando se detecte el cambio como ejemplo me muestre el `alert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si esos dos códigos pertenecen al mismo `$scope`, pero suponiendo que sí, lo primero que veo es que la variable `numero` no pertenece al `$scope`. Para que el siguiente código te detecte un cambio en la variable `numero`, esta última debe estar declarada de la siguiente manera:

```
$scope.numero = 0;

$scope.$watch("numero", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(oldValue, newValue);
});

$scope.llamar = function() {
    $scope.numero = 1;
}
```

Pero en cuanto a tu problema recuerda que en `JavaScript` puedes enviar como argumento a una función otra función y ejecutarla cuando lo necesites, creo que sería más sencillo hacer algo como esto:

```
$scope.numero = 0;

$scope.Cola = function (dispatch) {

    Ticket.Colaservices({

        id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
        token: LoginData.getData().token,
        id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
        id_moduloatencion: LoginData.getData().moduloatencion_id

    }, function(response) {

        $scope.DateCola = response.data;
        var rut = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data.rut.split('.').join('')));
        $scope.rutsinpunto = rut;

        if (dispatch) {

            dispatch.call($scope, $scope.numero, response.data.numero);

        }

        $scope.numero = response.data.numero;

    });

}

$scope.Cola();
```

Y después, desde tu método `llamar` puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$scope.llamar = function () {

    //mando ciertos datos
    Llamado.Llamar({
        id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
        token: LoginData.getData().token,
        id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
        id_moduloatencion: LoginData.getData().moduloatencion_id
    }, function(response) {

        $scope.Cola(function (oldvalue, newvalue) {

            console.log(oldvalue, newvalue);

        });

    });

}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido el primer ejemplo, Solo remplace 'var' por '$scope' y ahora funciona perfect!

Comment: Me quedo la duda sobre dispatch! me podrías explicar como funciona. te lo agradesco:D

Comment: `dispatch` es el nombre que le di al parámetro, puede ser cualquier nombre. Lo que intentaba explicar con ese código es que en `JavaScript` se puede enviar una función como parámetro a otra función. Para que lo entiendas he creado este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qje8e3hb/), mira el resultado en la consola para que entiendas el funcionamiento.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias te las mandaste :D y lo entendí perfect

Comment: De nada, un saludo ;)